# Why TensorFlow XLA needs many new xla op kernels?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, compiler-construction, xla

In TensorFlow code about XLA, I see kernels about many OPs like  [`compiler/tf2xla/kernels/concat_op`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/concat_op.cc).
It seems like a repetition of [`core/kernels/concat_op`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/concat_op.cc).
Why Ops like `compiler/tf2xla/kernels/concat_op` are needed? And why not just replace it with `core/kernels/concat_op` to save code?